# HAML class 2 if statements

Tags: ruby, haml

```
%li{class: ('active' if @current.empty?), class: ('disabled' if @past.empty?)}
```

What's the correct HAML syntax to dynamically add each of those 2 classes depending on each of those conditions (with Ruby)?

Comment: The correct thing to do is put the logic in your controller, do the test there, and assign the value to a variable you access in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array:

```
%li{class: [('active' if @current.empty?), ('disabled' if @past.empty?)]}
```

Any `nil` members of the array will be left out, and the remaining ones will be combined for the class attribute.